# Express vector $\mathbf v$ as linear combination of $\mathbf a_1$, $\mathbf a_2$, ..., $\mathbf a_n$

Tags: vectors

Let $\mathbf a_1=(a_{11},a_{12},\dots,a_{1n})$, $\mathbf a_2=(a_{21},a_{22},\dots,a_{2n})$, ..., $\mathbf a_n=(a_{n1},a_{n2},\dots,a_{nn})$ be $n$ linearly independent vectors.

Given $\mathbf v = \alpha_1 \mathbf a_1+\alpha_2 \mathbf a_2+\dots+\alpha_n \mathbf a_n$, how do I find $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ explicitly in terms of $a_{11},a_{12},\dots,a_{nn}$?

Comment: Since the vectors are linearly independent you can turn it into the standard basis $e_i$.

Comment: Try to think about a reduced problem: say you have a basis $\mathcal{A} = \left\{a_1, a_2\right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a vector $v = \alpha a_1 + \beta a_2$. What could you do now, maybe also using the canonical basis $\mathcal{E} = \{e_1, e_2\}$?